# Scatter 3D for Large Data-Set in Plotly

Tags: python, webgl, plotly, scatter3d

I have a 3D scatter which wanna plot using Plotly in python. The problem is size of the dataframe is too large and I want to use webgl to plot the graph. As I know plotly has `go.Scatter3d` function to plot scatters. Also, there is a `go.Scattergl` to plot large datasets. However, U can't find something like `go.Scatter3Dgl`. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe 3D scatter plots use webgl by default.  If you inspect a `scatter_3d` you'll find that it is in a `class="gl-container"`.  Likewise a regular `Scatter` is in a `class="main-svg` and a `Scattergl` is in a `class="gl-container"`.

From [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/#vector-formats-svg-and-pdf):

> Note: It is important to note that any figures containing WebGL traces
>   (i.e. of type scattergl, heatmapgl, contourgl, scatter3d, surface,
>   mesh3d, scatterpolargl, cone, streamtube, splom, or parcoords) that
>   are exported in a vector format will include encapsulated rasters,
>   instead of vectors, for some parts of the image.